# Coverting object into string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one doubt in stringify an object.

In input is below:

```
var obj = [{'name' : 'Jenisha', 'lastName' : 'dalin'}];
obj.__used = true;
```

My expected output:

```
JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4);
"[
    {
        "name": "Jenisha",
        "lastName": "dalin"
    }
],
"__used" : true
"
```

But the results are:

```
JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4);
"[
    {
        "name": "Jenisha",
        "lastName": "dalin"
    }
]"
```

"__used" param removed. is any alternate function available to stringify an object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From [MDN stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify): "String-keyed array elements are not enumerable and make no sense in JSON" In your example `obj` is not a a plain object, it's an array.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are essentially stringifying an array, a string key inside a JSON array representation makes no sense. This is also stated in the [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) documentation on MDN.

Since an array is stringified like this: `["value1", "value2"]`, and the keys are actually just numbers (0, 1, 2) and are left out, a string key as you added it is just ignored, because it cannot be represented in the output.

You can add both properties to an object and serialize this instead:

```
JSON.stringify ({
    arr: [{'name' : 'Jenisha', 'lastName' : 'dalin'}],
    used: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` works with valid JSON format. but seems your Obj has invalid JSON format.

To verify your JSON goto: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do not use [] in your code.

```
var obj = {'name' : 'Jenisha', 'lastName' : 'dalin'};
obj.__used = true;
```

Now if you stringify obj, you will get __used property as well.

Answer (score 0):

Json was prepared by library from  my side im just stringify that, while stringify the json the my object was getting removed. can we able over come this issue.

```
var obj = {'name' : 'Jenisha', 'lastName' : 'dalin'};
obj.__used = true;
```

This is how my json getting prepared